# Reaaragment of list data in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a list like

```
a=
:x1
..$y: chr [1:100] "da" "da" "dw" "dw"...........
..$z: num [1:100] 1 3 7 10 14 15 16...........
:x2
..$y chr [1:150] "sdd" "gtr" "fr" "sw"........
..$z num [1:150] 1 2 3 7 10 15 16............
```

i want to create a list which is a split of current list in a way that z vector should be split between 1:10, 11:20, 21:30,......

for eg.

```
a1=
:list1
..$x1
.. ..$y: chr [1:10] "da" "da"...........
.. ..$z: num [1:10] 1 3 7 10 ...........
..$x2
.. ..$y chr [1:10] "sdd" "gtr"........
.. ..$z num [1:10] 1 2 3 7 10............
:list2    
..$x1
.. ..$y: chr [1:10] "des" "ded"...........
.. ..$z: num [1:10] 14 15 16...........
..$x2
.. ..$y chr [1:10] "dwd" "ded"........
.. ..$z num [1:10] 15 16............
:list3    
..$x1
.. ..$y: chr [1:10] "ded" "sa"...........
.. ..$z: num [1:10] 21 24 27...........
..$x2
.. ..$y chr [1:10] "dww" "dw"........
.. ..$z num [1:10] 24 27 30............
```

I am trying some for loop but is throwing some errors.

Comment: reproducible example?

Comment: x = c()
 x1 = c()
 x2 = c()
 x1$a = c(1,2,3,4)
 x1$b = c("a","s","d","f")
 x2$a = c(1,3,5,6,7)
 x2$b = c("d","e","g","ds","fd")
 x = list(x1,x2)

use this to generate a dataset and split a column of each dataset in list in 1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8 and so on

Comment: the length of list is different for x1 and x2?

Comment: yes, dynamically i want to find in 1:2 which elements from x1 and x2 are there and so on

Comment: To get an answer, [make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610).

Comment: can X1 and X2 be two different dataframes?

Comment: yes but it in not fixed

Comment: What are `x1` and `x2`? Data frames? Lists? Please post the output of `str(a)`.

Comment: x1 and x2 are data frames in a list